# How to enable widget properties in GTKSharp (MonoDevelop)

Tags: c#, monodevelop, gtk#

Good day! I just want to ask if how could I enable widget properties in *GTKSharp*. It was already there before the first time I installed MonoDevelop. But now I can't find it . I already tried to enable it via **View > Pads > Properties** but it is different. It is in general properties, not the specific widget properties like in this example. When I clicked the button to edit its properties, I can't (e.g. editing the name value of the button, resizing, etc. via widget properties) like I did before.

How could I enable it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View > Pads > Properties is correct.

That pad is context sensitive, so you have to be in the Designer mode (stetic). Select any widget and the Properties Pad will show you the widget's Properties and Signals.